# Error in Android Studio while creating new project auto generated XML files

Tags: android-studio

[This an example for an XML file in my Android's project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z6Dz.jpg)

every time i build a new android studio , it builds wrong generated XML files
and i have tried many solutions like **Re-build** - **Clean Project** - even **Invalidate and Restart**
can someone help me to solve this one .. Thank You

Comment: provide screenshots and xml

Comment: did you check option generate layout file option?

Comment: Hi, your question is a bit vague. Please read over https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to add more information and clarity so you can get a good answer.

Comment: I've Provided an Image,

Comment: yes i did and it also keeps generating this XML error

Comment: okay thank you guys, i still have this problem i don't know what to do ?!

Answer (score -1):

okay i got your question & here i have solution i hope it will work

first thing is try to find that SDK is missing or not ?
second thing try to fix environment variables is set & working or not ?
then rename this files

goto C:/users/Admin/.AndroidStudio3.2/system/

Rename is file caches to caches.bak & restrat the studio